# Парсинг по списку страниц интернета из robots.txt

Tags: парсер, jsoup, java-8, sitemap

Необходимо читать все страницы, которые указаны в текстовом файле robots.txt

```
    public class SiteMapParcer {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            FileInputStream in = null;

            try {
                in = new FileInputStream("robots.txt");
                //in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\moshkov\\Desktop\\kraulerproject\\src\\main\\java\\robots.txt");
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(String.valueOf(in)).get();
             //print all available links on page
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            for (Element l : links) {
                System.out.println("link: " + l.attr("abs:href"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Но получаю ошибки:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: java.io.FileInputStream@677327b6
>   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:102)
>   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:44)
>   at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
>   at SiteMapParcer.main(SiteMapParcer.java:30)
> ```

Что я делаю не так и на верном ли я пути или же я все усложняю?

В файле robots.txt данные хранятся в следующем виде:

> Sitemap: https://www.bfm.ru/sitemap.xml

Comment: Код отправки запроса по url покажите и выведите url перед этим.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка в строке

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(String.valueOf(in)).get();
```

В метод `Jsoup.connect(url)` нужно передавать строку, содержащую URL. Запустите программу в отладчике и посмотрите, что вы передаёте в него ("java.io.FileInputStream@677327b6"). Реализуйте корректное чтение из файла robots.txt и вместо `String.valueOf(in)` передавайте строку URL.

UPD. Пример чтения из файла

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("robots.txt"));
while (sc.hasNext()){
    String url = sc.nextLine().split()[1]
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Я понимаю, но идея как раз была в том, что не один URL будет читаться, а несколько. Они в свою очередь лежат в файле, который нужно прочитать, а ссылка на файл  и есть in = new FileInputStream("robots.txt").  Хотелось бы реализовать такую логику...

Comment: Как раз чтения файла у вас и отсутствует. `String.valueOf(in)` не читает строки из файла. Вам нужна помощь с чтением файла?

Comment: Да, чтение файла. А FileInputStream - это не удачная реализация в моем случае? Я думал, что этот класс предназначен для чтения данных.

Comment: Дополнил ответ примером чтения из файла. Можно использовать и FileInputStream, этот способ будет содержать больше кода и будет работать быстрее. Scanner очень медленный.

Comment: если ответ вам помог, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).